# Creating CSS shapes with outlines

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a website, and for the navigation, I thought it would be coo, if i could use shapes, I am trying to avoid using images.

The specific shape I am trying to create is a crescent moon, with a border.

What I am trying to achieve:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to finish this shape with a border around the red, and the rest of the circle, not part of outline of the red, gone.

```css
.bottom_line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 500px;
  box-shadow: 100px 100px 0px 0px red inset;
}

.top_line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 110px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_line"></div>
<div class="bottom_line"></div>
```

Comment: This is a perfect case for SVG....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of fiddling around I have came up with this. Thanks, cpshah, your answer helped me come up with this.

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 500px;
  box-shadow: 100px 100px 0px 0px red inset;
}

.bottom_line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 110px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 500px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 0px -8px purple inset;
  z-index: 2;
}

.top_line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 510px;
  width: 510px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 510px;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 0px 7px purple inset;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="top_line"></div>
<div class="bottom_line"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image of dropbox, you do not want circle for inside arc.
So, you could use this for top_line class:

```css
.top_line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 110px;
  height: 430px;
  width: 430px;
  border-radius: 500px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 9px 10px 0px 0px black inset;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
  border-top-right-radius: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_line"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make the background color transparent